# Matplotlib in wxpython-plotting aborts

Tags: python, wxpython, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib in my wx.Frame to draw some arrows and text at a certain position. The number and position of the arrows is based on previously created data. 
I do some calculations but basically it's like this:

arrow = primer
for each primer:
draw one arrow at position y - 0.05 to the previos arrow (primer_y - 0.05).
The x position of the arrow comes from the data, which is calculated and scaled (not so important know, it's just to now where the arrow should be at primer_x).

Everything works fine until I have many arrows to draw. E.g. in my code example the data contain 62 arrows, where 18 are drawn correctly, the next 3 are missing but the text is there and the rest is completly missing.

Does anyone knows what could be the problem? I tried allready to change the FigureSize but it's only stretch the arrows.

Here's a quick and dirty working example, data is included in the code:
http://pastebin.com/7mQmZm2c

Any help is highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
Stefanie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Stick

   ```
           print((primer_x+0.06, primer_y))
   ```

   inside the loop. You'll find that the arrows cease to be drawn when
   `primer_y` becomes negative.
2. Don't draw the arrows with `self.axes.annotate` while labeling the
   arrow with `self.fig.text`. The axis and the figure use different
   coordinate systems. Changing `self.fig.text` to `self.axes.text`
   will allow you to use the same coordinate system, which will make it
   easier for you to position the text under the arrows.
3. There are far too many
   hard-coded numbers ("magic numbers") in your code. It makes it very
   hard to fix because when one number changes, the rest to do not change
   in a logical way along with it. If you can use formulas to define
   the relationship between some of those magic numbers, your life will
   be a lot easier.
4. For example, if you change the for-loop to

   ```
   for primer,primer_y in zip(data,np.linspace(0.95,0.0,len(data))):
   ```

   instead of decrementing `primer_y` by a fixed amount with each pass through the loop, then `primer_y` will automatically space itself between 0.95 down to 0.0 no matter how many items there are in `data`.
5. If you find the arrows are squished (vertically), you can expand the
   figure by changing the `figsize` on this line:

   ```
   self.fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(20, 30), facecolor='white')
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer and suggestions!